# C String array order manipulation

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on an exercise on a C course and I've run into a segmentation fault. This code is supposed to change the order of the array. Like, input: ad b c daa, output: daa c b ad. It changes by the space. So I used strtok to make it into tokens and for loops to change the order but I got an error. My question is what is a segmentation error: 11, and why am I getting one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void changeorder(int SIZE, char string[], char changed_string[]);

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 10;
    char string[SIZE];
    char changed_string[SIZE];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    strtok(string, " ");
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    if(string[len-1] == '\n') {
        string[len-1] = '\0';
    }
    changeorder(SIZE, string, changed_string);
}

void changeorder(int SIZE, char string[], char changed_string[]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=SIZE; i>0; i--) {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j--) {
            string[i] = changed_string[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the docs for strtok, it doesn't magically "turn it into tokens". And your example is 10 characters long, that doesn't fit in a `char[10]`, you're forgetting the null terminator.

Comment: regarding this line: fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); the code needs to check the return value from the fgets() function to assure that sizeof(string) bytes are read into string. (BTW: string is the name of a class in C++, so probably should not be used)

Comment: One problem is that `ad b c daa` uses 10 characters, so you haven't sized your arrays big enough to hold the data and the terminating null.  You're using `fgets()` which is good, but it means your data will be truncated after 9 characters.

Comment: @user3629249: the fact that `string` is a class name in C++ has zero impact on a C program.

Comment: Are you simply reversing the order of the 'words', or are you sorting them in reverse order?  With the shown input and output, either could be what you're doing, but sorting requires two loops (and some more code comparing entries) and simple reversal only requires one loop.

Comment: `string[i:10]` out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void changeorder(size_t len, char string[], char changed_string[]);

int main(void) {
    const int SIZE = 16;
    char string[SIZE];
    char changed_string[SIZE];

    printf("Enter string : ");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    strtok(string, "\n");
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    changeorder(len, string, changed_string);
    printf("'%s'\n", changed_string);
    return 0;
}

void changeorder(size_t len, char string[], char changed_string[]) {
    char temp[len];
    int i=0, k=0;
    while(len--){
        if(string[len] != ' ')
            temp[k++] = string[len];
        if(string[len] == ' ' || !len){
            while(k)
                changed_string[i++] = temp[--k];
            if(string[len] == ' ')
                changed_string[i++] = ' ';
        }
    }
    changed_string[i] = 0;
}
```